# Consistently override the DEBUG trap from a sourced script

Tags: bash, signals

I have a script that I source in my `.bashrc` which sets the `DEBUG` trap. This works fine, normally, but I recently discovered that if the `DEBUG` trap has previously been set (e.g. earlier in the `.bashrc`) the sourced `trap` call doesn't persist - it appears to be re-overwritten by the earlier trap.

Isolated Example:

```
$ env -i bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3$ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
bash-4.3$ cat /tmp/echotrap.sh 
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo "DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED"' DEBUG
bash-4.3$ source /tmp/echotrap.sh 
bash-4.3$ true
DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED
bash-4.3$ trap
DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
trap -- 'echo "DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED"' DEBUG
bash-4.3$ exit
DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED
exit
```

Notice that the `DEBUG` trap is set by sourcing `/tmp/echotrap.sh`, as I expected.

However if the `DEBUG` trap has already been set, this no longer works:

```
$ env -i bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.3$ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
bash-4.3$ trap : DEBUG
bash-4.3$ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
trap -- ':' DEBUG
bash-4.3$ source /tmp/echotrap.sh 
bash-4.3$ true
bash-4.3$ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
trap -- ':' DEBUG
bash-4.3$ exit
exit
```

The initial trap remains.

Is there any workaround for this issue (from within the sourced script)? I'd like to be able to update the `DEBUG` trap regardless of its current state, not only if it hasn't been set before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) page, in the `.` section:

> If the -T option is enabled, source inherits any trap on DEBUG; if it is not, any DEBUG trap string is saved and restored around the call to source, and source unsets the DEBUG trap while it executes. If -T is not set, and the sourced file changes the DEBUG trap, the new value is retained when source completes.

So, to make the trap stick, in the bash that `source`s your file (not in the `source`d file itself), do `set -T` before `source`ing.

Then your tests should pass.

However, this doesn't meet your stretch goal of being able to ensure that traps get installed *within* the `source`d script, without requiring the invoking user to set an option. Perhaps this is considered to be a security feature.

Regardless, whether or not the `source`d file does `set -T` itself, it only persists for the "scope" of the sourced file. This is true even if the `source`d file uses the `$BASH_SOURCE` variable to re-`source` itself a second time after setting `-T`. This implies the presence of some nested scope-like behavior in Bash that I wasn't previously familiar with; if those layered set/not-set behaviors persist to arbitrary depth in `source`d files, that could potentially be abused in interesting ways. Regardless, you can at least inform the user `source`ing your file that your traps probably won't work, by putting some code like this at the top of the file:

```
if [[ ! $- =~ T ]]; then
        echo "Can't install traps unless '-T' option is enabled; not loading library"
        return
fi
trap 'echo "DEBUG TRAP TRIGGERED"' DEBUG # Won't run unless -T has been enabled
```

Another option, if you don't want to place the burden on `source`d libraries to check for that sort of thing, is to override `source` itself with a function which conditionally overrides `trap`. Since function definitions *are* available to `source`d files, something like this would work:

```
function source() {
    if [[ ! $- =~ T ]]; then
        function trap() {
            if [[ $@ == *DEBUG ]]; then
                echo "Debug traps won't work in a source/.'d file unless the shell option -T is set before calling source/."
                return 1
            else
                builtin trap $@
            fi
        }
    fi
    builtin source $@
    unset trap
}
```

The function can't check whether the `DEBUG` trap is set before deciding to override `trap`, however; the same behavior that makes `DEBUG` traps provisionally invisible to `source`d code also makes them invisible inside functions. To work around that, you could pack the entire `source` function into an alias, which *does* have access to `DEBUG` traps, at the cost of readability (e.g. `alias source='if [[ ! $- =~ T && $(trap -p DEBUG) ]]; then echo SORRY; fi; builtin source'`).

This override can also be "defeated" by code that uses `builtin source` or `builtin type` directly.

Comment: Asking the caller to use `set -T` before calling `source` seems reasonable. I'd rather not add the `if [[ ! $- =~ T ]]` check though, since any user who isn't already setting the `DEBUG` trap doesn't need it. Any idea if there's a way to detect "You previously set a `DEBUG` trap *and* didn't set `-T` before sourcing this script"?

Comment: You could change the conditional to `if [[ ! $- =~ T && $(trap -p DEBUG) ]]` which would probably get the job done.

Comment: I think that without `-T` `trap -p DEBUG` will always be empty inside a sourced script. I'm guessing there's no clean way to tell whether the sourcing environment had a `DEBUG` trap set.

Comment: There is not a way to do that, no. There is an option to override `source` itself, however; I'll add that to my answer.